# Filling in missing fields in a SQL query

Tags: join, google-bigquery, looker-studio, coalesce

I am trying to combine data from two tables Budget and Actuals into a simple table I can use in a PivotTable in Google Looker Studio to compare actuals and budgeted. I manage to combine the tables and the financial data but I would also like to transfer other data from the budget table, like the account names to the new table also for the rows coming from the actuals. I'm quite new to SQL and I think I need to do it in two steps but I have not found out how.

The tables look like this:

tblActual:

| Date | Account | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1234 | 100 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1235 | -100 |

tblBudget:

| Date | Account | Balance | AccountType | AccountGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1234 | 150 | Sales | Income |
| 2023-01-02 | 1245 | -150 | Raw material | Expenses |

Now I have managed to combine these two with the following query:

```
SELECT coalesce(a.date, b.date) as date, coalesce(a.Account, b.Account) as Account, a.Balance as Outcome, Account as Budgeted, b.AccountGroup, b.AccountType
FROM tblActual a
full outer join tblBudget b 
ON (b.date = a.date and b.Account = a.Account)
ORDER BY datum DESC
```

That seems to work and I get a table like this:

| Date | Account | Outcome | Budgeted | AccountType | AccountGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1234 | 100 | null | null | null |
| 2023-01-02 | 1245 | -100 | null | null | null |
| 2023-01-01 | 1234 | null | 150 | Sales | Income |
| 2023-01-02 | 1245 | null | -150 | Raw material | Expenses |

But how can I make sure that the AccountTypes and AccountGroups in the new table are filled in also for the rows fetched from the tblActuals? So that all rows have their proper AccountTypes and AccountGroups (as defined in the tblBudget). Like the following:

| Date | Account | Outcome | Budgeted | AccountType | AccountGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1234 | 100 | null | Sale | Income |
| 2023-01-02 | 1245 | -100 | null | Raw material | Expenses |
| 2023-01-01 | 1234 | null | 150 | Sales | Income |
| 2023-01-02 | 1245 | null | -150 | Raw material | Expenses |

I am writing the query in Google BigQuery. Any help appreciated!

Best regards,
Fred

Answer (score 0):

From the data I see in the question you just need an inner join like so:

```
SELECT
       a.date
     , a.Account
     , a.Balance as Outcome
     , b.Budgeted
     , b.AccountGroup
     , b.AccountType
FROM tblActual a
INNER JOIN tblBudget b ON b.date = a.date and b.Account = a.Account
ORDER BY
       a.date DESC
     , a.Account
```

BUT, if those "dates" are timestamps (i.e. contain time not equal to midnight) then the inner join may not find any matches.